# Oracle - Changing the value of a single ordinance in a Geometry field

Tags: sql, oracle, geometry

I have a single Geometry Field in a table

```
select g3e_GEOMETRY from MyTable
where g3e_FID = 15463352
```

This returns

(3001, , (, , ), (1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 0, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ), (1920181.3264, 5801197.1585, 0, 0.345448182564728, 0.93843782594412, 0, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ))

Technically the same as

```
SELECT SDO_GEOMETRY(3001,NULL,NULL,
   SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1,1,4,1,0),
   SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1920181.3264, 5801197.1585, 0, 0.345448182564728, 0.93843782594412, 0)) AS g3e_GEOMETRY 
FROM dual;
```

Now I would like to change the 0.93843782594412 value say to 1.5

I can get the individual bits from the sdo_ordinances function

```
select g.* from table( select p.g3e_GEOMETRY.sdo_ordinates from MyTable p
where g3e_FID = 15463352) g;
```

This returns a table with a single column called COLUMN_VALUE

```
1920181.3264
5801197.1585
0
0.345448182564728
0.93843782594412
0
```

But I now do not know the SQL required to create the update statement so I can update the **0.93843782594412** value to **1.5**.

From what I have been reading you must update the whole sdo_ordinate array at once. So really I somehow need to generate the line below (with the old values + my replacment value)

```
SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1920181.3264, 5801197.1585, 0, 0.345448182564728, 1.5, 0)
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Chris

Comment: Have you try `REPLACE` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a bit of PL/SQL code.

```
declare
   l_geometry mdsys.sdo_geometry;
begin
   -- Get the geometry from the table into the variable.
   select g3e_geometry
     into l_geometry
     from mytable
    where g3e_fid = 15463352;

   -- Now you can do whatever you want with it.
   l_geometry.sdo_ordinates(5) := 1.5;

   -- Write back to the table
   update mytable
      set g3e_geometry = l_geometry
    where g3e_fid = 15463352;
end;
```

Since your suggested update seems a bit random, that's all I can make of it at this moment.